# PointF a Centimetros c#

Tags: c#

estoy trabajando con un printdocument en el cual la posición la asigno con variables PointF, pero quiero saber cuantas unidades de este tipo de varibles equivalen a un centímetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver como puedo explicartelo, esto no es una regla que valga para todo. PointF es una structura que tiene 2 propiedades X y Y de tipo double, estas dos propiedades marcan un PIXEL, exacto de la pantalla.

Por lo que preguntas, tu tendrías, lo primero si quieres medir un centímetro hacia arriba/abajo (Y) o hacia Izda/Dcha (X).

La conversión es más complicado pq depende de la definición y pantalla de cada usuario, normalmente las pantallas suelen tener 96 dpi, que son pixels por pulgada. A esto tienes que añadirle que 1 pulgada son 2.54 cm, ya solo te queda hacer la regla de 3 y ya lo tienes.

1 cm = 1 / 2.54 = 0.393701 pulgadas
1 pulgada tiene 96 pixels.
1 cm tiene 96 * 0.393701 = 37.795296 pixels

Y en código, algo así:

```
    public double CmAPixels(int cm)
    {
        return 96 * 0.393701 * cm;
    }


    public void Main()
    {
        PointF.X = CmAPixels(10);
    }
```

Recuerda que siempre depende de la resolución y pantalla del usuario.

Comment: por que el numero 10 va en ese parentesis?

Comment: olvidalo... me ha servido tu ayuda